# Angular: Invoking a method when counter variable value is 0

Tags: angular, setinterval, angular-directive

I'm running `setInterval` in my constructor in Angular which decreases a variables value by 1 each second:

```
setInterval(() => 
   this.counter = this.counter - 1
    , 1000);
```

When `this.counter = 0`, I want to invoke a method in the current component. Is there any angular directive that will run a method based on a certain variables value?

Comment: Why do you need a directive to do that?

Comment: Can't you just do inside `setInterval` `if (this.counter === 0) { callSomething() }`?